# How to change MediaPlayer playback rate in Android 4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Has someone managed to do that ?

Would it be possible to add Android 6 MediaPlayer's `setPlaybackParams()` method to a subclass of Android 4's MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "setPlaybackRate(int)".

Comment: That's a method of the AudioTrack class, which lacks the seekTo() method